# HTTP - Tipos corretos de retorno

Tags: spring, http, spring-boot, http-status

Tenho alguns questionamentos a respeito dos status mais adequados para cada situação a seguir:

1. **PUT** em Objeto sem Id

**PUT** na URL **localhost:8080/usuarios/1** com um JSON sem o atributo Id.

2. **PUT** em Objeto com Id diferente do parâmetro

**PUT** na URL **localhost:8080/usuarios/1** com um JSON com o Id 2, ou seja, diferente do que foi passado no parâmetro.

3. **GET** com parâmetro inválido

**GET** na URL **localhost:8080/usuarios/busca?sexo=ABC**, ou seja, um sexo inválido para o sistema (o correto seria sexo=masculino ou feminino).

4. **POST** de JSON já com id.

Realizar um **POST** com objetivo de persistir algum dado **novo**, porém já com o id.

Comment: Victor, basicamente você quer saber qual o tipo de retorno http mais indicado para cada um desses casos né?

Comment: Exatamente. Para fazer o tratamento correto do Status na minha aplicação

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se a pergunta é relevante dado o tempo que foi perguntado. De qualquer forma, aí vai a minha contribuição:

A resposta ideal seria **400: Bad Request** para todos os cenários que você apresentou. Entendo que nesses casos apresentados o cliente enviou uma requisição incorreta para ser interpretada pelo servidor.

Vou procurar detalhar cada cenário.

> 1. PUT em Objeto sem Id
>    PUT na URL localhost:8080/usuarios/1 com um JSON sem o atributo Id.

Informe no detalhe do erro a interface esperada pela requisição. Como você está utilizando o plural da semântica (usuario**s**), pode retornar a lista dos usuários cadastrados. A URL `/usuario` (singular) sem o Id deve responder com status 400 e informar no detalhe do erro o problema.

> 2. PUT em Objeto com Id diferente do parâmetro
>    PUT na URL localhost:8080/usuarios/1 com um JSON com o Id 2, ou seja, diferente do que foi passado no parâmetro.

Neste caso, você pode tomar dois caminhos:

1. Ignorar o enviado no JSON e tomar como verdade o da URL ou;
2. Retornar um código de erro 400 conforme coloquei acima informando da inconsistência.

> 3. GET com parâmetro inválido
>    GET na URL localhost:8080/usuarios/busca?sexo=ABC, ou seja, um sexo inválido para o sistema (o correto seria sexo=masculino ou feminino).

O mesmo status 400. Inconsistência na requisição informando no detalhe do erro o valor dos parâmetros esperados.

Neste caso você poderia sintetizar a sua URL para `localhost:8080/usuarios/?sexo=ABC`. Sem a palavra **busca**. Isso porque os parâmetros na URL já conotam a pesquisa.

> 4. POST de JSON já com id.
>    Realizar um POST com objetivo de persistir algum dado novo, porém já com o id.

Você pode lidar da mesma forma que em #2. Ignorar o Id enviado ou retornar o erro explicando a inconsistência.

Sugiro também definir um domínio para os erros retornados, como por exemplo:

```
{ 
  codigo: 0001, 
  mensagem: 'o parâmetro sexo pode receber como valor apenas feminino ou masculino. Corrija a requisição e tente novamente', 
  status: '400' ... 
}
```

Isso não exclui você retornar o status HTTP correto.

Para mais informações, consulte essa página: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html